# hid touchpad not working but detected

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, touchpad, atom

I tried to install xubuntu 16.04.1 made for Atom's (bay trail) instead of pre-installed Win 10 on my netbook. But after installation touchpad doesn't work although it is detected by **xinput list** as "HID 1018:1006 Touchpad". What should i do? Is there any possibility to take drivers from Win 10 and use it in linux?. Please help. I'm new in linux. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: did you plug in a (wireless) mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that this touchpad is not supported yet by Linux.

You can't use Windows driver.

You can report it to Launchpad by running in terminal

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

If you want to get it working sometime be prepared to give feedback.